# In EF 4.1 is it possible to set a field to null with a stub entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Is it possible to set a field to null in EF using a stub entity?

I want my code to work like so:

```
 MyEntity myEntity = new MyEntity() { ID = detached.ID };
 ctx.MyEntities.Attach(myEntity);
 // The value in the table is non null, the value in detached is null.
 myEntity.myNullableField = detached.myNullableField;
 ctx.SaveChanges();
```

What I am currently seeing is that if I set a field to null in the myEntity stub object EF detects it as no change, and does not update that column in the database. Is there some way to force EF to detect the null as a change so it will save it into the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting a field which is null (because you've just created a brand new blank entity) and then assigned null to it, so there is no change.

You can mark the property as modified if you do the following:

```
 ctx.Entry(myEntity).Property(e => e.myNullableField).IsModified = true;
```

Feels like a bit of a hack unfortunately though.

Comment: My understanding is that the whole point of the stub, was to allow you to skip the read from the database before every write.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood. Updated answer.

Comment: Ultimately went with: `ctx.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(myEntity).SetModifiedProperty(propertyName);` but same general idea. Thanks for the help.